# Need help creating proper JSON

Tags: json, string

Here is my raw 'pseduoJSON' provided to me:

```
{ providers: [{id: 1, name: “Perry Cox”}, {id:2, name: “John Dorian”}, {id:3, name: “Christopher Turk”}] }
```

Can someone help me parse this into proper JSON? I am having trouble using JSON Lint getting it formatted (its been a couple years).

Comment: add a " around those keys

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out. Having copied the original text without pasting it as plain text, I was getting those fancy curly double-quotes, rather than 'normal' double-quotes.

Once I noticed that, I simply formatted it a little more standard-ly and was finished:

> {     "providers": [      {
>           "id": 1, 
>           "name": "Perry Cox"       },          {
>           "id": 2, 
>           "name": "John Dorian"         },          {
>           "id": 3, 
>           "name": "Christopher Turk"
>                 }   ]  }